# Can only select one metaball any others are only conneteced to the first

Tags: objects, selection-tools, meta-objects

Hi when I add in metaballs only one can be selected and moved, moving it rotates the other balls, and I can't move the others, this is only with metaballs. Here's a video showing what I mean https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dMSJwpvO9PE&feature=youtu.be

Comment: You video doesn't work for me. Can you post A still image of your scene and outliner? Be aware that Metaballs have an edit mode, so the others may have been created 'inside' the main one in edit mode.

Comment: @Sazerac Sorry! I had the video as private and not unlisted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meta-objects, like many other objects, have an edit mode. In edit mode you can create more meta-objects that are part of the first, and will be transformed all together when they are transformed in object mode.

Meta-objects will still stick together regardless of the whether they have been created in object or edit mode

Answer (score 1):

with Metaballs you need to select the invisible circle around the Metaballs to move them.